# Python: trouble with inherited class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I have two classes. `producto`, with the following class definition:

```
class producto(object):

    def __init__(self, precio, nombre, _id, cantidad):

        self.__precio = precio
        self.__nombre = nombre
        self.__id  = _id
        self.__cantidad = cantidad
```

And `alimentacion` with the following class definition:

```
class alimentacion(producto):

    def __init__(self, precio, nombre, _id, cantidad, dias_caducidad):

        super(alimentacion, self).__init__(precio, nombre, _id, cantidad)

        self.__dias_caducidad = dias_caducidad
```

When I try to instantiate a member of the class `alimentacion` like so,

```
salmon = alimentacion(15, 'salmón', 435, 2, 15)
```

I get the following error:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/Ale/PycharmProjects/ticket/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ale/PycharmProjects/ticket/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from clases.tipos_producto import *
  File "C:\Users\Ale\PycharmProjects\ticket\clases\tipos_producto.py", line 4, in <module>
    class alimentacion(producto):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Copy pasting the error was too hard?

Comment: Please paste the error

Comment: Furthermore it works fine for me. So I think you probably run this with an old version, or there are other aspects in the code that you do not provide.

Comment: The line of code you claim to be the cause of the error doesn't even show up in the traceback. Whatever it is you're doing wrong, it's not part of the code you posted.

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/1513933

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error, your `producto` class is defined in a module, also named `producto`, and you're importing and inheriting from the module, not the class. Change:

```
class alimentacion(producto):
```

to:

```
class alimentacion(producto.producto):
```

so you inherit from the class defined in the module.